# Storage Networking On-Topic?

Tags: discussion

With the advent of converged switching fabric, there is a great potential for overlap between storage and data networking. Being an integral part of the data center environment, I feel that the overlap is permissible. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm wondering if we should post these sorts of Qs with two answers. That way people can up vote the answer of their choosing, rather than having an up/down voting battle in one answer?

Comment: after some comments to/from RCartaino, I'm dropping my secondary answer; see below.

Answer (score 13):

YES, storage and data networking questions would be ON TOPIC.

Comment: For future reference, it's typically best to let users be heard with their own answers, rather than posting in this pseudo-polling format. Pre-posting *all* sides of the conversation isn't necessarily the best way to get the clearly-vetted results you seek: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Polling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion

Comment: for posterity: RC's comment might seem out of context. At the time, I had posted a second answer enticing/encouraging people to vote poll-style. His comment is here, on this answer, to keep it from being lost when my second/uneeded answer was deleted.