# No points earned for *answers* to meta questions, right?

Tags: support

...I was thinking it looks nicer to post two answers for the yea/nea sort of meta questions. (to wit [Storage Networking On-Topic?](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/storage-networking-on-topic) )

BUT, I don't want it to seem that I'm trying to game the system for points. I *think* no points are earned for up/down votes of answers in Meta. Right?

Comment: The points are actually tracked. They will show up in moderator elections: http://serverfault.com/election http://i.imgur.com/CkPysT1.png

Comment: ok. Yet another reason to NOT post multiple answers ala poll-style. It really would be an inappropriate sort of point stuffing.

Comment: Upvote for a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can appreciate what you are trying to accomplish, but it's best to simply ask the questions and let others be heard in a open forum. It's typically best to let users be heard with their own answers, rather than posting in this pseudo-polling format.

Pre-posting *all* sides of the conversation isn't necessarily the best way to get the clearly-vetted results you seek: [Polling is not a substitute for discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aPolling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion).

I left the questions, but removed the canned responses. But please feel free to contribute you own thoughts on the issue. Thanks.

Comment: doh. I was deleting this as you're commenting... upvoted and accepted for posterity. :)

Comment: @CraigConstantine It's a good issue/signpost to hash out and leave for others to learn from.

Comment: over here http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65/storage-networking-on-topic , you deleted my first answer -- that was a real answer initially posted. Deleting it whacks 5 people's up votes? ...but I didn't want to undelete it.

Comment: @CraigConstantine Ah, okay. I restored that post.

Comment: I think my 'polling' puddle-stomping answers are now all cleaned up. :)